# Disable mobile while user is driving at certain speed?

Tags: android, gps

I need to add a feature to our mobile application which is "to disable the mobile device while user is driving at certain speed". Is this  a good idea to listen to the `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` & use the getSpeed()? Can someone comment on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to record the previous location and then check with the new location in a particular interval of time(preset to 5-10sec) and the get the distance moved in a time frame to get speed.
Its a good concept but it will drain your device battery.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good idea, but it requires GPS to be activated.
Anyway, other providers won't be accurate enough.

You can consider toggling GPS on with your application, but it is pretty intrusive and could drain battery quickly...